# Show data from mutiple sanity apis

Tags: javascript, api, sanity

Quick question. I want to show images from multiple sanity sanity api's. How can I render this in one getserversideprops function or is there a better way to do this? Here's how I am getting data onto the page from one sanity api. How can I get data from two/ multiple sanity apis (onto the same page)?

```
const api_key = process.env.API_KEY



const index = ({ posts }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [mappedPosts, setMappedPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (posts.length) {
      const imgBuilder = imageUrlBuilder({
        projectId: 'xxxxxxxx',
        dataset: 'production'
      });

      setMappedPosts(
        posts.map(p => {
          return {
            ...p,
            mainImage: imgBuilder.image(p.mainImage).fit('min'),
          }
        })
      )

    } else {
      setMappedPosts([0])
    }
  }, [posts])

return (
<>
<Row style={rowStyle}>
          <div className="h1" id="btf--SelectedWork__Text">Selected work</div>
          {mappedPosts && mappedPosts.slice(0, 12).map((post) => (
            <Col lg="3" className='imgTopPad'>
              <p className="h3">{post.title}</p>
              <div style={imageContainerStyle} onClick={() => router.push(`./atfs/${post.slug.current}`)} key={post.index} >
                <img
                  src={post.mainImage}
                  alt={post.title}
                  style={imgStyle}
                  layout="fill" />
              </div>

            </Col>

          ))}
        </Row>
</>
)
}

export const getServerSideProps = async pageContext => {
  // get posts from our sanity api
  const query = encodeURIComponent(`*[ _type == "post"]`); // loads particular page slug - encodeURI encodes query
  const url = `https://` + api_key + `.api.sanity.io/v1/data/query/production?query=${query}`;
  const result = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json()); // calls data and coverts it to json

  if (!result.result || !result.result.length) {
    return {
      notfound: true
    }
  } else {
    return {
      props: {
        posts: result.result,
      }
    }
  }
}

export default index
```

Comment: you can use RXJS operators https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin check this url for reference